# Remove this error?

Tags: windows-10

[image]

How we can remove above error in Windows 10.  Due to this error, all the applications like Microsoft Word and other applications are not opening within Windows 10.

Comment: A side by side error means you have part of a Visual Studio C++ redistributable missing. I have no idea how to figure out which one... unless someone else does, then you'll need to install them all until it works :/

Comment: I downloaded the exe files of Visual Studio C++.But When I start them same errors appears.As in the System all exe files are not running they are generating the same error meaasge.

Comment: Within the Microsoft Answers realm, people have found success by running the SFC and DISM commands.  Others discovered that their Google Chrome install was corrupted.  [Take a look at their recommendations](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/windows-10-error-the-application-has-failed-to/5c6a015e-4162-491d-b7d9-f3b13612e304?auth=1).

Comment: what does the information say in the associated application event log entry?

Comment: you can use the program "dependency walker" and drag&drop the exe that is failing into dependency walker. On the upper left there will be a list of "red" or missing dependencies. do you see any red dll thats name is starting with VC